# i want to hide comment in drupal 7 which is displayed like Submitted by Anonymous (not verified) on Sat, 09/05/2015 - 04:15

Tags: comments

i  want to hide comment in Drupal7 which is displayed like Submitted by Anonymous (not verified) on Sat, 09/05/2015 - 04:15

Comment: Well, then go on and hide it. What's your problem? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: To just hide the information "*Not verified*" in comment, go to your theme setting and under *Toggle Display* uncheck the chekbox named as "User verification status in comments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the **Author username** and **Publish Date** by editing the content type from

`Structure > content types > YOUR CONTENT TYPE`

[image]